# Octave axes zoom redraw

Tags: octave, axis-labels, axes, yaxis

I am facing an issue in Octave. When I set custom tick labels of y axis, labels are not updated correctly when zoomed. It is easy to solve in Matlab:

```
plot(1:10);
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%,.1f';
```

My code with faulty y labels when zoomed:

```
ax2 = gca;
ytick = get (ax2, "ytick"); 
yticklabel = strsplit (sprintf ("%9.0f\n", ytick), "\n", true); 
set (ax2, "yticklabel", yticklabel);
```

The above code formats y tick labels properly, but labels does not match plot when zoomed. There is a screenshot of my issue: [nonzoomed vs zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyF0L.jpg). 
I am using W10 64bit, Octave version 4.0.3.. Octave was configured for "i686-w64-mingw32".

Any ideas?

I have decided to add minimal code example to be more clear about the issue:

```
x=1:length(inv);
figure
hax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
stairs(x,inv);
hax2 = subplot(2,1,2);
x=1:length(mon);
% big numbers here, need to format to get rid of scientific notation
stairs(x,mon); 
ax2 = gca;
ytick = get (ax2, "ytick"); 
yticklabel = strsplit (sprintf ("%9.0f\n", ytick), "\n", true); 
set (ax2, "yticklabel", yticklabel);
linkaxes([hax1 hax2],'x');
```

Comment: You could check some of the octave documentation on axis configuration, but it shouldn't be plotting using incorrect y-axes just from zooming in.What version are you using/operating system, etc? That could help us reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using W10 64bit, Octave version 4.0.3.. Octave was configured for "i686-w64-mingw32".